# (Javascript) How to move div to its original position with pure javascript and check if the scroll bar is out of the visible area

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using Javascrpt, I want to move my video to the bottom of the page
when my web visitors scrolls down outside the video visible area,
just like this website :
http://download.cnet.com/DL-Driver-Updater/3000-18512_4-76115428.html

I have 2 questions :
1. How to move div to its original position with pure javascript ?
2. How to Check if the scroll bar is out of the visible area ?

Here's what I have so far :
https://jsfiddle.net/jojoco/5n062fcu/

```js
function yScrollHandler(){
   var win = document.getElementById("styleku-video-container");
    // if the scrool bar is outside the visible area of the original video
   if((window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight) >= document.body.offsetHeight){
   win.style.transition = "right 0.7s ease-in-out 0s";
   win.style.right = "0px";
   win.style.position = "fixed";
   win.style.bottom = "0px";
   win.style.padding = "10px";
   win.style.width = "400px";
   win.style.height = "225px";
   } else {
   //back to original position
   }
 }
 window.onscroll = yScrollHandler;
```

```css
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p {
   font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  }
  h1{
   font-size: 36px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: red;
  }
  h2{
   font-size: 32px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: blue;
  }
  h3{
   font-size: 28px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: green;
  }
  h4{
   font-size: 24px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: orange;
  }
  p {
   font-size: 16px;
  }
  .container {
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 960px;
   margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .styleku-center {
   text-align: center;
  }
  #styleku-video-container iframe, #styleku-stealth-video iframe {
   border: 5px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container styleku-center">
 
 <h1>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
 </h1> 

 <div id="styleku-video-container">
  <iframe width="400" height="225" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/H0LI8vFq_Es" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>

 <p>
   Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. <br/><br/>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. <br/><br/>Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. <br/><br/> Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.<br/>
 </p>

 <h2>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
 </h2> 

 <p>
   Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. <br/><br/>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. <br/><br/>Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. <br/><br/> Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.<br/><br/>
 </p>
 <h3>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
 </h3> 

 <p>
   Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. <br/><br/>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. <br/><br/>Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. <br/><br/> Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.<br/><br/>
 </p>

 <h4>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
 </h4> 

 <p>
   Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. <br/><br/>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. <br/><br/>Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. <br/><br/> Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.<br/><br/>
 </p>

</div>
```

Comment: Just a suggestion but if you plan to use the youtube player for the video why not use the player API? This way you can track if the player is actually playing before applying events to keep the video in view while scrolling. This will also enable you to snap the video back to its original position when the video has ended... Just an idea I thought might make things a little better. Without this you will experience the following: The video will position when out of view even if the client isn't watching it making it useless and no doubt in the way.

Comment: Thanks for your suggest. I plan to embed from other video hosting sites, not just from youtube, therefore I need to modify the js and css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```js
function yScrollHandler(){
  var win = document.getElementById("styleku-video-container");
  // if the scrool bar is outside the visible area of the original video
  if((window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight) >= 750){
    win.style.transition = "right 0.7s ease-in-out 0s";
    win.style.right = "0px";
    win.style.position = "fixed";
    win.style.bottom = "0px";
    win.style.padding = "10px";
    win.style.width = "400px";
    win.style.height = "225px";

  } else {
    win.removeAttribute("style");
  }
}
window.onscroll = yScrollHandler;
```

```css
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  }
  h1{
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
  }
  h2{
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: blue;
  }
  h3{
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: green;
  }
  h4{
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: orange;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .styleku-center {
    text-align: center;
  }
  #styleku-video-container iframe, #styleku-stealth-video iframe {
    border: 5px solid red;
  }
  #cont1 {
    style: relative;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container styleku-center">

 <h1>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
 </h1>

 <div id="styleku-video-container">
  <iframe width="400" id="miframe" height="225" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/H0LI8vFq_Es" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>

 <p>
   Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. <br/><br/>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. <br/><br/>Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. <br/><br/> Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.<br/>
 </p>

 <h2>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
 </h2>

 <p>
   Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. <br/><br/>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. <br/><br/>Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. <br/><br/> Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.<br/><br/>
 </p>
 <h3>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
 </h3>

 <p>
   Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. <br/><br/>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. <br/><br/>Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. <br/><br/> Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.<br/><br/>
 </p>

 <h4>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
 </h4>

 <p>
   Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. <br/><br/>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. <br/><br/>Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. <br/><br/> Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.<br/><br/>
 </p>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your code. It works :) Please let me ask some questions : 1.what is the use of this line : var height = document.getElementById("miframe").clientHeight;

2.The iframe will be an input from the user, so I can not manually hardcode this id="miframe". Any idea how to make it work ?

Comment: You can skip that line i have changed the code Please check! :)

Comment: Awesome. Really appreciate it. Can I also remove the id="miframe" on the <iframe> ?

Comment: yes you can remove it there is not need for that now